# Black Screen after ubuntu update16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

Hi Everyone, 
                     I have updated my ubuntu 16.04 today and after the successful update,when i restarted my system it is showing just a black screen.I have crucial data in my system and can't wipe it out.Pretty depressed.I have no clue what to do as i am not able to login to system.Please please help!!
The screen after restart is:
https://postimg.org/image/rb700nych/
And the error log when i press F4 key is:
https://postimg.org/image/jlyeh1kjl/

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? We cannot help you if we don't know what you have.

Comment: @ҐрадонХатчінсон Sir,It is lenovo z50 laptop and when i press F4 key it shows "nvidea adapter probed" kind of problem and then shows a screen with logs which says "unable to handle kernel paging request at ...". Now i dont know what to do..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your computer boots up, after the BIOS loads, press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, to see all available Ubuntu boot options.

Choose `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and then choose the `Ubuntu, with Linux ... (recovery mode)`, preferably the one with the oldest version of the kernel.

If you can safely login to Ubuntu, backup all your files. If this is all you need, then you can re-install Ubuntu. Otherwise after you back up your files, let me know so that we can see if we can diagnose your system's problem and fix it.

---

#### Update 1

Great, now that you have managed to login, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, this should show you a terminal screen. Then using the [`cp` command](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cp1.html), backup all your important files.

For example, if your external HDD is mounted at `/run/media/my-hdd`, first create a directory there named `backup-2016-07-17`:

```
$ cd /run/media/my-hdd
$ mkdir backup-2016-07-17
```

Then run the following command:

```
$ cp -R /home/your-username /run/media/my-hdd/backup-2016-07-17
```

---

#### Update 2

Also please run the following command to list all the errors that have occurred in this boot session:

```
journalctl -b -p err..emerg
```

Then please add them to your question. For example, for me, it shows the following output:

```
Jul 16 16:58:40 localhost kernel: tpm_tis 00:0a: A TPM error (6) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
Jul 16 16:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script.
Jul 16 16:58:40 localhost kernel: iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
Jul 16 16:58:40 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script.
Jul 16 16:58:41 localhost kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
Jul 16 16:58:41 localhost NetworkManager[898]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Jul 16 16:58:41 localhost wpa_supplicant[1227]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Jul 16 16:58:41 localhost wpa_supplicant[1227]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Jul 16 16:58:41 localhost wpa_supplicant[1227]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wls2 flags: No such device
Jul 16 16:58:43 localhost kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
Jul 16 16:58:47 localhost kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-19)
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jul 16 16:58:50 localhost bluetoothd[1482]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jul 16 16:58:59 localhost pulseaudio[1940]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Comment: Sir,with your suggestion,I am able to see the login screen now but when it redirects to the HomeScreen after login then a certain black screen appears/fluctuates and again the login screen appears again.Resulting i am not able to enter into system.

Comment: @user3652697 Please check my **Update 1**. By the way, does your computer have a CD/DVD drive? Or do you have Ubuntu installation media on a CD/DVD or a USB key?

Comment: Thankyou so much!   journalctl -b -p err..emerg ihelped me.with this i found that nvidia purge error was occuring.Then i run command          Sudo apt-get purge nvidia*   and finally problem resolved.Thankyou thankyou so much!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help. :)